# Post-apocalyptic novel with four female protagonists, one a marksman

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

I spotted a book in Walmart a few days ago but forgot to note its name.

It was either post-apocalyptic or set *during* the apocalypse. It has four female leads, one of whom was (I think) mentioned as being a marksman on the cover. A snippet inside the book mentioned a gun. The others were (I recall) some kind of biologist, and another a surveyor. It mentioned

> “*...nature has reclaimed...*”

and I know the author is a man. I believe the book is recent but I’m not sure.

Comment: How recent is recent? Did it look like it may have been published in the last 2 years? 10? 30?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [Annihilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation_(VanderMeer_novel)) by Jeff VanderMeer.

> It is the first in a series of three books called the Southern Reach
>   Trilogy. The book describes a team of four women (a biologist, an
>   anthropologist, a psychologist, and a surveyor) who set out into an
>   area known as Area X. The area is abandoned and cut off from the rest
>   of civilization. They are the 12th expedition. The other
>   expeditions have been fraught with disappearances, suicides,
>   aggressive cancers, and mental trauma.

[image: Cover of *Annihilation*]

It may have appeared recently in WalMart due to the [2018 film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation_(film)) adapted from the book.

### Trailer

Comment: yes! thank you so much!!! i’ve been looking for it on and off for a few hours now, thank you!!

Comment: [You're welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)