# Movie where heroine wakes up to a mirror image enemy that copies her every move?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Do you remember the movie where the heroine wakes up to a mirror image enemy that copies her every move and she tries to escape but the mirror image follows her, ultimately suffocating her by copying her every move while she fights it? The only way she defeats it is by playing dead or something, lying on the ground, then laying a bomb/grenade on the enemy because the enemy is a copycat but does not have any of the equipment except the heroine's physical structure.

It was in a room with sand, the copycat might have been one of many obstacles; the movie was not too old (like 2000's +), and the girl might have been Natalie Portman.

Comment: Couple of questions - When you say mirror image, do you mean there's an actual mirror involved? What is the "equipment" you mention? What was the nature of the enemy? Plain old human, some kind of demon/entity?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out; it is actually the movie I am watching right now xD It was 'annihilation' ; I guessed I watched a clip of that scene before seeing the actual movie.

Comment: Nice! Please post it as a self-answer in the field below :)

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182843/post-apocalyptic-novel-with-four-female-protagonists-one-a-marksman (about the novel on which the film is based)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

'Annihilation' (2018)

Some weird scene worth watching where Natalie Portman fights her shadow image (not unlike Link vs Dark Link in the Water Temple).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2798920/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt):

> At "Area X", a government facility on the southern coast of the US, Lena, a cellular-biology professor and former soldier, is in quarantine. She undergoes a debriefing about a four-month expedition into an anomalous iridescent electromagnetic field dubbed "the Shimmer", of which she and her husband, Kane, are the only survivors. In flashback, Kane, an Army Special Forces soldier, appears in their home after having disappeared on a mission nearly a year ago. He remembers nothing of that time and suddenly falls very ill. A government security force intercepts Kane's ambulance and transports him and Lena to Area X, near where the Shimmer had begun to spread three years earlier..

Scene in question:

Comment: Literally the first thing I thought of when I read OP's question.